# Java programs don't repaint GUI after Ubuntu update

Tags: java, bug-reporting

After I updated Ubuntu yesterday, Java programs don't update their GUI after the initial update. When moving the mouse over the GUI things that respond to mouse movements will show up on an unrelated background:

[image]

This is very inconvenient for me as this is my work PC and I'm a Java developer.

Today's Ubuntu updates didn't change anything. I updated Java to Oracle JDK 8u202 and OpenJDK 8u191, tried both, and both show the same behavior. (I know when my programs are running in either JDK because of the differences in font rendering.) The only Java program that doesn't seem to be affected is IntelliJ running on the JetBrains VM, but I cannot use this VM for development because we require Java 8 (and not newer).

[edit] I found and installed JetBrains JDK 8u202 and it has the same problems.

Before you ask, it's not a problem with *my* programs. It also happens to NetBeans, to older versions from the repo, and there are graphical glitches (nothing serious) in Firefox. So the root cause may not be *specifically* related to Java.

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS using Gnome on Xorg
- Compiz 0.9.13.1
- Intel HD Graphics 530

[Update] I re-installed Ubuntu for other reasons (with keep home directory) and it's fixed. The question is still open as to what caused it and how it can be solved?

[Update2] After I installed wine (and dependencies) The exact same problem came back again. It must be one one of these 141 packages. How do I find out which causes the problem?

> <pointless package list was here>

[Update3] I uninstalled wine and all dependencies (`apt autoremove`) and uninstalled even more, and the problem persists.

Comment: Based on your images, I suspect that the default font/image size has changed, or screen scaling, and needs to be reduced. Are you running the default theme?

Comment: yes. font is "Ubuntu" and scaling is and always was 100%. This is a mockup GUI for a 5 inch display device, hence the big fonts and hacked scroll bar width.

Comment: reduce your font size and see if it improves the display

Comment: What has the font size of this program have to do with anything? Did you read the part where NetBeans and other java programs are also affected?

Answer (score 0):

Not going to help much, but just tried to use SweetHome3D on my laptop and it exhibits the same behavior. Worked few weeks ago.

Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS / Gnome, Lenovo X230.

Then again, SweetHome3D works with my desktop which has nVidia graphics.

Something Intel related?

Comment: Please ask your query on comments section.

Comment: @M.A.K.Ripon New users can't comment.